# bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, docker, ssh, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to build a deployment pipeline *(similar to GitHub actions)* for a python Django project managed in Bitbucket. The pipeline consists of two steps *(actions)*,

1. Build a docker image and push it to Amazon ECR *(No issues here)*
2. SSH into the deployment server, pull and deploy the image

Here is my deployment code that executes in the SSH session,

```bash
# deployment.sh

( echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY & echo $AWS_REGION & echo "" ) | aws configure

docker login -u AWS -p $( aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION ) $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com
docker pull $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/usyd-sams

rm -r -f sams

if [[ $DEPLOYMENT == "staging" ]]
then
    git clone -b main --single-branch $GIT_URL
fi

if [[ $DEPLOYMENT == "production" ]]
then
    git clone -b develop --single-branch $GIT_URL
fi

( cd sams && docker-compose up -d)
```

Traceback,

```
INFO: Executing the pipe...
INFO: Using default ssh key
INFO: Executing script deployment.sh on ec2-0-0-0-0.west.compute.amazonaws.com
ssh -i /root/.ssh/pipelines_id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 someone@ec2-0-0-0-0.west.compute.amazonaws.com DEPLOYMENT=staging AWS_REGION=west AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_KEY AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET POSTGRES_USER=someuser POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD POSTGRES_DB=somedb bash -s
Warning: Permanently added the ED25519 host key for IP address '0.0.0.0' to the list of known hosts.
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The first step works flawlessly but the second seems to raise an error that I've been stuck with for hours now. Here is my pipeline configuration,

```yaml
      - step:
          deployment: staging
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.4.1
              variables:
                SSH_USER: $SSH_USER
                SERVER: $SSH_ADDRESS
                MODE: 'script'
                COMMAND: 'deployment.sh'
                ENV_VARS: >-
                  DEPLOYMENT=staging
                  AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION}
                  AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}
                  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_KEY}
                  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET}
                  POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
                  POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
                  POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
```

Comment: `echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY & echo $AWS_REGION & echo ""` is almost certainly not what you want.  You almost certainly want `&&` in all of those.

Comment: @Yasiru: Complementing the comment by William Pursell : I don't see how the `echo` could fail. Therefore the `&&` is also not needed and you could just perform the statements sequentially. However I would quote the variables; otherwise any run of spaces would be compressed into a single space, when piped into `aws`.

Comment: I don't have much experience with bash, what do you mean by performing statements sequentially?

Comment: You probably don't need that `aws configure` line at all; if those environment variables are set then all of the following `aws` commands will honor them.  Does the `aws ecr get-login-password` command work if you run it as a standalone command?

Comment: @Yasiru `cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3` runs `cmd1`, `cmd2`, and `cmd3` *all at the same time*, meaning the order in which they do things (in this case, the order the various strings gets printed) is left partly up to chance. That's not what you want. You want them run one after the other in order ("sequentially"), so you should separate them with semicolons. (Note: this is a potential problem, but I don't see how it could be causing the error in the title. But you should fix it anyway.)

Comment: Just try it: `echo "foo" & echo "bar" & echo "roo" & echo ""`: 3 processes are launched in parallel to do that.

Comment: @user1934428, echo can fail if stdout is not a writable file descriptor (or it's writable, but to a device that reports an I/O error, etc). It's rare, but it happens.

Comment: BTW, not the cause of the problem, but your code is missing a bunch of quotes. Consider running it through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here as a matter of course.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Sure, but you get an error message then. In this case, all `echo` in that subprocess would fail, and nothing would be input into `aws`. The same effect would be achieved if we just use `;` as separator.

Comment: You get an error message _if stderr isn't failing the same way_. And if there hasn't been any redirection, that's pretty likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Clearly indicates that whatever command is supposed to be feeding "deployment.sh" to bash, is not doing it correctly.

I would replace the whole "deployment.sh" script with a single `echo "foobar"` or something equally simple just to make sure that the script runs. Then, I would dump all the environment variables `env` to see if there's something funky.

Eventually check piece by piece that everything in "deployment.sh" is working correctly, and for starters others have already pointed out you have an issue at the beginning:

This:

```
echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY & echo $AWS_REGION & echo ""
```

Runs four commands in parallel, and the order of the output isn't guaranteed, which clearly would mess with `aws configure`.

Instead use a heredoc:

```bash
aws configure <<EOF
$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
$AWS_REGION

EOF
```

This shouldn't affect the rest of the script though.